# Swift 3 table search

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I have populated a table using json data from a remote server.

I am now trying to add a search bar which will filter the results.

The issue I am facing is that I am storing the json data in several arrays.

name, company, job title etc

This means that when the user searches only the name array is filtered and displayed in the table correctly, the other information is out of sync as it remains unfiltered.

Am I approaching this in the correct way?

```html
class attendees: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate {

    var tableData = ""

    var value:String!

    var searchString = ""

    var firstname: [String] = []
    var lastname: [String] = []
    var fullname: [String] = []
    var company: [String] = []
    var jobtitle: [String] = []
    var image: [String] = []


    var filteredAppleProducts = [String]()
    var resultSearchController = UISearchController()

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        print(value)



        searchBar.delegate = self



        self.tableView.reloadData()

        let nib = UINib(nibName: "vwTblCell2", bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell2")


    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        getTableData()

    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


        if filteredAppleProducts != []{

            return self.filteredAppleProducts.count
        }
        else
        {

            if searchString != "[]" {
            return self.firstname.count
            }else {
                return 0
            }
        }

    }


    // 3
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell  {
        let cell2: TblCell2 = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2") as! TblCell2

        print(filteredAppleProducts)


         if filteredAppleProducts != []{

            cell2.nameLabel.text = self.filteredAppleProducts[indexPath.row]

            return cell2
        }
        else
        {
            if searchString != "[]"{
            cell2.nameLabel.text = "\(self.firstname[indexPath.row]) \(self.lastname[indexPath.row])"
                cell2.companyLabel.text = self.company[indexPath.row]
                cell2.jobTitleLabel.text = self.jobtitle[indexPath.row]


                let url = URL(string: "https://www.asmserver.co.uk/wellpleased/backend/profileimages/\(self.image[indexPath.row])")
                let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check / try-catch
                cell2.userImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)

            }
            return cell2


        }
    }

    // 4
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }

    // 5
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 90
    }


    func updateSearchResults(){


        self.filteredAppleProducts.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

        let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchString)
        let array = (self.fullname as NSArray).filtered(using: searchPredicate)
        self.filteredAppleProducts = array as! [String]

        self.tableView.reloadData()

        print(filteredAppleProducts)


    }


    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        print("searchText \(searchText)")
        print(filteredAppleProducts)

        searchString = searchText
         updateSearchResults()
           }

    func getTableData(){

        self.firstname.removeAll()
        self.lastname.removeAll()
        self.fullname.removeAll()
        self.company.removeAll()
        self.jobtitle.removeAll()
        self.image.removeAll()


        let defaults = UserDefaults()
        let userid = defaults.string(forKey: "id")

        let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.asmserver.co.uk/wellpleased/backend/searchattendees.php?userid=\(userid!)&eventid=\(value!)")

        print(url)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url as! URL) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            if let urlContent = data {

                do {

                    if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: []) as? [[String:AnyObject]] {


                        var i = 0

                        while i < jsonResult.count {


                            self.firstname.append(jsonResult[i]["firstname"]! as! String)
                            self.lastname.append(jsonResult[i]["lastname"]! as! String)

                            let fname = jsonResult[i]["firstname"]! as! String
                            let lname = jsonResult[i]["lastname"]! as! String
                           let fullname1 = "\(fname) \(lname)"

                            self.fullname.append(fullname1)

                            self.company.append(jsonResult[i]["company"]! as! String)
                            self.jobtitle.append(jsonResult[i]["jobtitle"]! as! String)
                            self.image.append(jsonResult[i]["image"]! as! String)




                            i = i + 1

                        }

                    }

                } catch {

                    print("JSON serialization failed")

                }

            } else {

                print("ERROR FOUND HERE")
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in

                self.tableView.reloadData()

            })

            self.tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }

        task.resume()

    }
}
```

Comment: i am facing the same problem can someone give me the code ...it will be very helpfull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a struct or class for the data. This way it'll be easier to keep track of the data, and in any case it looks like you don't have any good reason to keep track of seven different arrays.

As an example:

```
struct Data {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var fullName: String
    var company: String
    var jobTitle: String
    var image: String
}
```

And populate just the one array:

```
var dataSource: [Data] = []
```

Access with property name, instead of `arrayName[index]`:

```
let name = dataSource[index].firstName
```